# SQL SUM within Query and Group By Duplicates

Tags: sql, function, sum, aggregate-functions, alias

Here is the Scenario:

Tables:
**CallMain:**

Call_ID = PK (INT)
Abandoned (INT) Either 1 or NULL

**CallHold:**

Hold_ID = PK (INT)

Call_ID = FK (INT)

StartTime (INT)

EndTime (INT)

Each call held in the CallMain table can have either 1, 0 or many hold records. Each time the call goes on hold an record is created referenced by the FK with the StartTime of the hold and the EndTime of the hold.

Now, to return this information in a query to show calls and their total hold times, I believe the SQL to be as follows:

```
SELECT CallMain.Call_ID, CallMain.Abandoned,  
ISNULL((CallHold.EndTime - CallHold.StartTime),0) AS HoldPeriodSeconds 
FROM CTIStatCall 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CallHold ON CallMain.Call_ID = CallHold.Call_ID
```

This query should return records for calls that have no hold records associated with them and should return them as NULLS. Calls with a single hold record appear correctly. The NULLS that are being returned by the LEFT OUTER JOIN are being managed with the ISNULL() function and being replaced with a zero as in effect that call has no hold time.

My problem is that where a call has multiple hold records it will appear twice in the result i.e:
Call_ID, HoldPeriod

212, 254

213, 154

214, 158

214, 25

214, 10
As can be seen above, Call 214 has multiple hold records totalling 193. I figured out that the query has to be:

```
SELECT
    CallMain.Call_ID,
    CallMain.Abandoned,  
    Sum(ISNULL((CallHold.EndTime - CallHold.StartTime), 0)) AS HoldPeriodSeconds 
FROM
    CallMain
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    CallHold
ON
    CallMain.Call_ID = CallHold.Call_ID
GROUP BY
    CallMain.Call_ID,
    CallMain.Abandoned
```

My question now is I have further columns in the MainCall table which are also going to be returned, CallStart, CallAns, CallEnd and these are used to calculate some other derived values. I am returning these and adding them to the group by clause but it goes back to displaying duplicate values again. How can I fix this?

I already tried:

> ```
> SELECT CallMain.Call_ID, dateadd(s,CallMain.StartTime, '1970-01-01') AS StartTime,
> dateadd(s,CallMain.AnsTime, '1970-01-01') AS AnsTime, 
> dateadd(s,CallMain.EndTime, '1970-01-01') AS EndTime,
> CallMain.Abandoned,
> (CallMain.AnsTime - CallMain.StartTime) AS RingPeriod,
> SUM(ISNULL((CallHold.EndTime - CallHold.StartTime),0)) AS HoldPeriod,
> (CallMain.EndTime - CallMain.AnsTime) - ISNULL((CallHold.EndTime - CallHold.StartTime),0) AS TalkPeriod
> FROM CallMain
> LEFT OUTER JOIN
> CallHold ON CallMain.Call_ID = CallHold.Call_ID
>    GROUP BY CallMain.Call_ID, CallMain.Abandoned, CallMain.StartTime, CallMain.EndTime, CallMain.AnsTime, CallHold.EndTime, CallHold.StartTime
> ```
>
> order by CallMain.Call_ID

Answer (score 0):

As you already said yourself. You get multiple results back when you group by `CallStart`, `CallAns`, `CallEnd`. This means you have more then 1 unique value of these columns for each `Call_ID, Abandoned` combination.

You have to decide which of these values you want to display. For example, you could choose to take the maximum values like this:

```
SELECT
    CallMain.Call_ID,
    CallMain.Abandoned,  
    Sum(ISNULL((CallHold.EndTime - CallHold.StartTime), 0)) AS HoldPeriodSeconds,
    (MAX(CallMain.AnsTime) - MAX(CallMain.StartTime)) AS RingPeriod,
    ....
FROM
    CallMain
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    CallHold
ON
    CallMain.Call_ID = CallHold.Call_ID
GROUP BY
    CallMain.Call_ID,
    CallMain.Abandoned
```

Or, perhaps more logical, use the `SUM` function like you did for HoldPeriod. I do not know what your expecting as a result though.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are grouping by

```
CallHold.EndTime , CallHold.StartTime
```

Which are giving back multiple entries, since your were getting one row per entry in CallMain. These need to be removed from the group by and either removed from the select statement or suitable aggregate functions used. It should be something like this...

```
SELECT CallMain.Call_ID, dateadd(s,CallMain.StartTime, '1970-01-01') AS StartTime,
       dateadd(s,CallMain.AnsTime, '1970-01-01') AS AnsTime, 
       dateadd(s,CallMain.EndTime, '1970-01-01') AS EndTime,
       CallMain.Abandoned,
       (CallMain.AnsTime - CallMain.StartTime) AS RingPeriod,
       SUM(ISNULL((CallHold.EndTime - CallHold.StartTime),0)) AS HoldPeriod,
       (CallMain.EndTime - CallMain.AnsTime) - ISNULL((CallHold.EndTime - CallHold.StartTime),0) AS TalkPeriod
  FROM CallMain
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       CallHold ON CallMain.Call_ID = CallHold.Call_ID
GROUP BY CallMain.Call_ID, CallMain.Abandoned, CallMain.StartTime, CallMain.EndTime, CallMain.AnsTime
```